# Including animation resources

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Hey I've been trying to include two animations into a third animation for the sake of modularity.  I have a fade in animation in one file:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fillAfter="true">
</alpha>
```

and a slide in animation in another file

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-50%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="1">
</translate>
```

I would like a third resource that just calls the two animations sequentially

```
<!--psuedo code-->
<set
    android:ordering="together">
    <animation android:animation="@anim/fade_in"/>
    <animation android:animation="@anim/slide_in"/>
</set>
```

Is there any way to do this?  Or do I have to create a set that contains all the animation properties that were defined in the previous files?

Comment: * Or do I have to create a set that contains all the animation properties that were defined in the previous files?* - this is the way to go, there's no way to embed other animations.

Comment: @Luksprog, thanks for your response. I'll take that route then.